# IIS 7 - Bad request(400) on post request

Tags: c#, iis

Very weird scenario:

We have a client which sends http requests to out cloud api's. It's running for about a month without a problem.

Suddenly I see that for one of our API's the client keeps on getting a 400 error. To all other API urls it reaches successfully.

I did some testing with fiddler and got this behavior:

```
url: Post request to - https://cloud-url.com/api1.aspx - success
url: Post request (with body x=1)to - https://cloud-url.com/api2.aspx - 400 error(bad request -VERB)
url: Post request (without body)to https://cloud-url.com/api2.aspx - success! 
url: Post request (with body 123)to https://cloud-url.com/api2.aspx - success!
```

Comment: There seems to be no question here.. no code to debug..?

Comment: can you see anything else in the 400 response (e.g. in the body). If it's a web API app and the model validation has failed, the validation errors might be in the response, depending how it's set up

Comment: validation is 403, there is some problem with the post params on their url

Comment: @BugFinder The code is fine, its not in the code level, something about the environment, maybe someone had cameout with this senario. The question is what can cause this kind of wired behavior, I never saw anything like it